# Local Push Notification Enable Sound

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification

Does anybody knows how to enable Sound on a Local push notification? By that, I mean that I am creating the notification from the device. I am not using APNS or anything related. Right now, the notification comes in but there is no sound. Is it possible to enable the notifications sound?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UILocalNotification` class has a `soundName` property. You should assign it to a sound name of a file that you have included in the app's bundle, or you can use `UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName` for the default iOS sound.

More information on the sound files supported [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103).

Comment: perfect! I should of tried looking into the properties.